# World Bank JSONP Parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

This should be very straight forward, but even looking at the other questions, I can't get it to work.

I'm retrieving some sample world bank data from the following link:

[World Bank Query](http://api.worldbank.org/countries/GBR/indicators/DC.DAC.FINL.CD?per_page=100&date=1960:2012&format=jsonP&prefix=getWorldBankData)

This returns the following JSONP structure:

```
getWorldBankData([
{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "per_page": "100",
    "total": 52
},
[
    {
        "indicator": {
            "id": "DC.DAC.FINL.CD",
            "value": "Net bilateral aid flows from DAC donors, Finland (current US$)"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": "GB",
            "value": "United Kingdom"
        },
        "value": null,
        "decimal": "0",
        "date": "2011"
    },
    {
        "indicator": {
            "id": "DC.DAC.FINL.CD",
            "value": "Net bilateral aid flows from DAC donors, Finland (current US$)"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": "GB",
            "value": "United Kingdom"
        },
        "value": null,
        "decimal": "0",
        "date": "2010"
    },
```

I want to get the title of the countries. I had been trying to do so with the following code:

```
function getWorldBankData(json){
    $.each(json.country ,function(){
        var country = "<option>"+this.value+"</option>"
        $('#category').append(country)
    });
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
    a is undefined
f()jquery.min.js (line 16)
a = undefined
c = function()
d = undefined
getWorldBankData()oil.js (line 11)
json = [Object { page=1, pages=1, per_page="100", more...}, [Object { indicator={...}, country={...}, decimal="0", more...}, Object { indicator={...}, country={...}, decimal="0", more...}, Object { indicator={...}, country={...}, decimal="0", more...}, 49 more...]]
DC.DAC.FINL.CD?per_page=100&date=1960:2012&format=jsonP&prefix=getWorldBankData()DC.DAC...ankData (line 1)
[Break On This Error]   

...all(b,0))}}var b=arguments,c=0,d=b.length,e=d,g=d<=1&&a&&f.isFunction(a.promise)...
```

It doesn't like this line (line 11):

```
$.each(json.country ,function(){
```

What is the correct way to get the country? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think json.country is going to work since that array is one level deeper in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed that and tried json..country but that didn't work. How do I skip a blank level?

Comment: Claudio's answer probably works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but something like this should do the trick

```
function getWorldBankData(json){
    var item;
    var itemArray = json[1];
    for (var i in itemArray ) {
        item = itemArray[i];
        $('#category').append("<option>"+ item.country.value+"</option>");
    };
}
```